# PL/SQL: Can't Resolve 'PLS-00103' and 'ORA-06550' Errors with Cursor and Indexed Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I need to create a query that simply passes a parameter into a cursor and BULK Collect the results to  table. Afterward, display the table columns. I have been researching other folk's questions and tried to rule out the issue but I think it may be related to the LOOP/END on the 2nd Cursor code but I haven't figured it out yet:

So my questions are:

- Q1: What is causing this error and how do I resolve it?
- Q2: To show the columns in the indx_tab table, should I put the
  out_put line    after closing the 2nd cursor? (I think so but I
  wanted to make sure).

Here is the script in question:

```
SET serveroutput ON;

DECLARE 

    Cursor emp_ID is SELECT Employee_ID FROM EMPLOYEES;
    Cursor all_emp_cur (ID employees.Employee_ID%TYPE) is 
              select a.first_name, A.EMAIL from employees a, job_history b
              where a.employee_id = b.EMPLOYEE_ID
              and b.employee_ID = ID;

    emp_rec employees%rowtype;
    TYPE indx IS TABLE OF emp_rec%rowtype
    INDEX BY pls_integer;
    indx_tab  indx;

    Tablecount number (10) := 0;
    Reccount  number (10) := 0;

BEGIN 

For ID_rec in emp_ID LOOP 
reccount := reccount + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

    Open all_emp_cur (ID_rec.Employee_ID) 
    Loop
    Fetch all_emp_cur bulk collect into indx_tab;

          --Tablecount := Tablecount + SQL%ROWCOUNT;
          Exit when all_emp_cur%NOTFOUND;
          END loop;
          Close all_emp_cur;

           /*FOR indx IN 1 .. indx_tab.count loop
           --dbms_output.put_line('Count: ' || rowcount)
           dbms_output.put_line('FIST NAME: ' || indx_tab(indx).fname);
           dbms_output.put_line('SALARY ' || indx_tab(indx).salary);

           --Begin: IF or Case Statements ---

          ---End: End If or Case Statements ---

          dbms_output.put_line('Row Count ' || Tablecount);*/

End Loop;

END;
```

Errors:

```
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 23, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( % ;
The symbol "; was inserted before "LOOP" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 44, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Here are the create table and insert statements:

```
  CREATE TABLE "EMPLOYEES" 
   (    "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
    "PHONE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "HIRE_DATE" DATE, 
    "JOB_ID" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "SALARY" NUMBER(8,2), 
    "COMMISSION_PCT" NUMBER(2,2), 
    "MANAGER_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "DEPARTMENT_ID" NUMBER(4,0)
   );


CREATE TABLE "JOB_HISTORY" 
   (    "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "START_DATE" DATE, 
    "END_DATE" DATE, 
    "JOB_ID" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "DEPARTMENT_ID" NUMBER(4,0)
   );




SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (100,'Steven','King','SKING','515.123.4567',to_date('17-JUN-03','DD-MON-RR'),'AD_PRES',24000,null,null,90);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (101,'Neena','Kochhar','NKOCHHAR','515.123.4568',to_date('21-SEP-05','DD-MON-RR'),'AD_VP',17000,null,100,90);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (102,'Lex','De Haan','LDEHAAN','515.123.4569',to_date('13-JAN-01','DD-MON-RR'),'AD_VP',17000,null,100,90);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (103,'Alexander','Hunold','AHUNOLD','590.423.4567',to_date('03-JAN-06','DD-MON-RR'),'IT_PROG',9000,null,102,60);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (104,'Bruce','Ernst','BERNST','590.423.4568',to_date('21-MAY-07','DD-MON-RR'),'IT_PROG',6000,null,103,60);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (105,'David','Austin','DAUSTIN','590.423.4569',to_date('25-JUN-05','DD-MON-RR'),'IT_PROG',4800,null,103,60);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (106,'Valli','Pataballa','VPATABAL','590.423.4560',to_date('05-FEB-06','DD-MON-RR'),'IT_PROG',4800,null,103,60);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (107,'Diana','Lorentz','DLORENTZ','590.423.5567',to_date('07-FEB-07','DD-MON-RR'),'IT_PROG',4200,null,103,60);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (108,'Nancy','Greenberg','NGREENBE','515.124.4569',to_date('17-AUG-02','DD-MON-RR'),'FI_MGR',12008,null,101,100);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (109,'Daniel','Faviet','DFAVIET','515.124.4169',to_date('16-AUG-02','DD-MON-RR'),'FI_ACCOUNT',9000,null,108,100);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (110,'John','Chen','JCHEN','515.124.4269',to_date('28-SEP-05','DD-MON-RR'),'FI_ACCOUNT',8200,null,108,100);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (111,'Ismael','Sciarra','ISCIARRA','515.124.4369',to_date('30-SEP-05','DD-MON-RR'),'FI_ACCOUNT',7700,null,108,100);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (112,'Jose Manuel','Urman','JMURMAN','515.124.4469',to_date('07-MAR-06','DD-MON-RR'),'FI_ACCOUNT',7800,null,108,100);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (113,'Luis','Popp','LPOPP','515.124.4567',to_date('07-DEC-07','DD-MON-RR'),'FI_ACCOUNT',6900,null,108,100);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (114,'Den','Raphaely','DRAPHEAL','515.127.4561',to_date('07-DEC-02','DD-MON-RR'),'PU_MAN',11000,null,100,30);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (115,'Alexander','Khoo','AKHOO','515.127.4562',to_date('18-MAY-03','DD-MON-RR'),'PU_CLERK',3100,null,114,30);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (116,'Shelli','Baida','SBAIDA','515.127.4563',to_date('24-DEC-05','DD-MON-RR'),'PU_CLERK',2900,null,114,30);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (117,'Sigal','Tobias','STOBIAS','515.127.4564',to_date('24-JUL-05','DD-MON-RR'),'PU_CLERK',2800,null,114,30);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (118,'Guy','Himuro','GHIMURO','515.127.4565',to_date('15-NOV-06','DD-MON-RR'),'PU_CLERK',2600,null,114,30);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (119,'Karen','Colmenares','KCOLMENA','515.127.4566',to_date('10-AUG-07','DD-MON-RR'),'PU_CLERK',2500,null,114,30);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (120,'Matthew','Weiss','MWEISS','650.123.1234',to_date('18-JUL-04','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_MAN',8000,null,100,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (121,'Adam','Fripp','AFRIPP','650.123.2234',to_date('10-APR-05','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_MAN',8200,null,100,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (122,'Payam','Kaufling','PKAUFLIN','650.123.3234',to_date('01-MAY-03','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_MAN',7900,null,100,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (123,'Shanta','Vollman','SVOLLMAN','650.123.4234',to_date('10-OCT-05','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_MAN',6500,null,100,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (124,'Kevin','Mourgos','KMOURGOS','650.123.5234',to_date('16-NOV-07','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_MAN',5800,null,100,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (125,'Julia','Nayer','JNAYER','650.124.1214',to_date('16-JUL-05','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',3200,null,120,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (126,'Irene','Mikkilineni','IMIKKILI','650.124.1224',to_date('28-SEP-06','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',2700,null,120,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (127,'James','Landry','JLANDRY','650.124.1334',to_date('14-JAN-07','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',2400,null,120,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (128,'Steven','Markle','SMARKLE','650.124.1434',to_date('08-MAR-08','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',2200,null,120,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (129,'Laura','Bissot','LBISSOT','650.124.5234',to_date('20-AUG-05','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',3300,null,121,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (130,'Mozhe','Atkinson','MATKINSO','650.124.6234',to_date('30-OCT-05','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',2800,null,121,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (131,'James','Marlow','JAMRLOW','650.124.7234',to_date('16-FEB-05','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',2500,null,121,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (132,'TJ','Olson','TJOLSON','650.124.8234',to_date('10-APR-07','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',2100,null,121,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (133,'Jason','Mallin','JMALLIN','650.127.1934',to_date('14-JUN-04','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',3300,null,122,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (134,'Michael','Rogers','MROGERS','650.127.1834',to_date('26-AUG-06','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',2900,null,122,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (135,'Ki','Gee','KGEE','650.127.1734',to_date('12-DEC-07','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',2400,null,122,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (136,'Hazel','Philtanker','HPHILTAN','650.127.1634',to_date('06-FEB-08','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',2200,null,122,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (137,'Renske','Ladwig','RLADWIG','650.121.1234',to_date('14-JUL-03','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',3600,null,123,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (138,'Stephen','Stiles','SSTILES','650.121.2034',to_date('26-OCT-05','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',3200,null,123,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (139,'John','Seo','JSEO','650.121.2019',to_date('12-FEB-06','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',2700,null,123,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (140,'Joshua','Patel','JPATEL','650.121.1834',to_date('06-APR-06','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',2500,null,123,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (141,'Trenna','Rajs','TRAJS','650.121.8009',to_date('17-OCT-03','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',3500,null,124,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (142,'Curtis','Davies','CDAVIES','650.121.2994',to_date('29-JAN-05','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',3100,null,124,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (143,'Randall','Matos','RMATOS','650.121.2874',to_date('15-MAR-06','DD-MON-RR'),'ST_CLERK',2600,null,124,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (146,'Karen','Partners','KPARTNER','011.44.1344.467268',to_date('05-JAN-05','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_MAN',13500,0.3,100,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (147,'Alberto','Errazuriz','AERRAZUR','011.44.1344.429278',to_date('10-MAR-05','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_MAN',12000,0.3,100,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (148,'Gerald','Cambrault','GCAMBRAU','011.44.1344.619268',to_date('15-OCT-07','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_MAN',11000,0.3,100,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (149,'Eleni','Zlotkey','EZLOTKEY','011.44.1344.429018',to_date('29-JAN-08','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_MAN',10500,0.2,100,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (150,'Peter','Tucker','PTUCKER','011.44.1344.129268',to_date('30-JAN-05','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',10000,0.3,145,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (151,'David','Bernstein','DBERNSTE','011.44.1344.345268',to_date('24-MAR-05','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',9500,0.25,145,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (152,'Peter','Hall','PHALL','011.44.1344.478968',to_date('20-AUG-05','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',9000,0.25,145,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (153,'Christopher','Olsen','COLSEN','011.44.1344.498718',to_date('30-MAR-06','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',8000,0.2,145,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (154,'Nanette','Cambrault','NCAMBRAU','011.44.1344.987668',to_date('09-DEC-06','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',7500,0.2,145,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (155,'Oliver','Tuvault','OTUVAULT','011.44.1344.486508',to_date('23-NOV-07','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',7000,0.15,145,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (156,'Janette','King','JKING','011.44.1345.429268',to_date('30-JAN-04','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',10000,0.35,146,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (157,'Patrick','Sully','PSULLY','011.44.1345.929268',to_date('04-MAR-04','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',9500,0.35,146,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (158,'Allan','McEwen','AMCEWEN','011.44.1345.829268',to_date('01-AUG-04','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',9000,0.35,146,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (159,'Lindsey','Smith','LSMITH','011.44.1345.729268',to_date('10-MAR-05','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',8000,0.3,146,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (160,'Louise','Doran','LDORAN','011.44.1345.629268',to_date('15-DEC-05','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',7500,0.3,146,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (161,'Sarath','Sewall','SSEWALL','011.44.1345.529268',to_date('03-NOV-06','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',7000,0.25,146,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (162,'Clara','Vishney','CVISHNEY','011.44.1346.129268',to_date('11-NOV-05','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',10500,0.25,147,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (163,'Danielle','Greene','DGREENE','011.44.1346.229268',to_date('19-MAR-07','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',9500,0.15,147,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (164,'Mattea','Marvins','MMARVINS','011.44.1346.329268',to_date('24-JAN-08','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',7200,0.1,147,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (165,'David','Lee','DLEE','011.44.1346.529268',to_date('23-FEB-08','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',6800,0.1,147,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (166,'Sundar','Ande','SANDE','011.44.1346.629268',to_date('24-MAR-08','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',6400,0.1,147,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (167,'Amit','Banda','ABANDA','011.44.1346.729268',to_date('21-APR-08','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',6200,0.1,147,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (168,'Lisa','Ozer','LOZER','011.44.1343.929268',to_date('11-MAR-05','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',11500,0.25,148,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (169,'Harrison','Bloom','HBLOOM','011.44.1343.829268',to_date('23-MAR-06','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',10000,0.2,148,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (170,'Tayler','Fox','TFOX','011.44.1343.729268',to_date('24-JAN-06','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',9600,0.2,148,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (171,'William','Smith','WSMITH','011.44.1343.629268',to_date('23-FEB-07','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',7400,0.15,148,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (172,'Elizabeth','Bates','EBATES','011.44.1343.529268',to_date('24-MAR-07','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',7300,0.15,148,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (173,'Sundita','Kumar','SKUMAR','011.44.1343.329268',to_date('21-APR-08','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',6100,0.1,148,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (178,'Kimberely','Grant','KGRANT','011.44.1644.429263',to_date('24-MAY-07','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',7000,0.15,149,null);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (179,'Charles','Johnson','CJOHNSON','011.44.1644.429262',to_date('04-JAN-08','DD-MON-RR'),'SA_REP',6200,0.1,149,80);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (180,'Winston','Taylor','WTAYLOR','650.507.9876',to_date('24-JAN-06','DD-MON-RR'),'SH_CLERK',3200,null,120,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (181,'Jean','Fleaur','JFLEAUR','650.507.9877',to_date('23-FEB-06','DD-MON-RR'),'SH_CLERK',3100,null,120,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (182,'Martha','Sullivan','MSULLIVA','650.507.9878',to_date('21-JUN-07','DD-MON-RR'),'SH_CLERK',2500,null,120,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (183,'Girard','Geoni','GGEONI','650.507.9879',to_date('03-FEB-08','DD-MON-RR'),'SH_CLERK',2800,null,120,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (184,'Nandita','Sarchand','NSARCHAN','650.509.1876',to_date('27-JAN-04','DD-MON-RR'),'SH_CLERK',4200,null,121,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (185,'Alexis','Bull','ABULL','650.509.2876',to_date('20-FEB-05','DD-MON-RR'),'SH_CLERK',4100,null,121,50);
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID,SALARY,COMMISSION_PCT,MANAGER_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID) values (186,'Julia','Dellinger','JDELLING','650.509.3876',to_date('24-JUN-06','DD-MON-RR'),'SH_CLERK',3400,null,121,50);
commit;
```

Here is the updated script to show the indx_tab (table) with column results:

```
BEGIN 

For ID_rec in emp_ID LOOP 
reccount := reccount + 1;

    Open all_emp_cur (ID_rec.Employee_ID) ;
    Fetch all_emp_cur bulk collect into indx_tab;

    Close all_emp_cur;

           FOR i IN indx_tab.first .. indx_tab.last loop
           --dbms_output.put_line('Count: ' || rowcount)
           dbms_output.put_line('FIST NAME: ' || indx_tab(i).fname);
           dbms_output.put_line('SALARY ' || indx_tab(i).salary);

           --Begin: IF or Case Statements ---

          ---End: End If or Case Statements ---
          End Loop;

End Loop;

 dbms_output.put_line('Row Count ' || reccount);

END;
```

Error:

```
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 29, column 62:
PLS-00302: component 'FNAME' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 29, column 12:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 30, column 58:
PLS-00302: component 'SALARY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 30, column 12:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in your code, first don't need to use a for to bulk collect a cursor into a table, and second the type of `indx` must be the same of the cursor. Look that cursor `all_emp_cur` have rows with `a.first_name, A.EMAIL` and you want to bulk collect it into a collection of type `indx` which can contains rows like `emp_rec%rowtype`(employees%rowtype). That's why i change the table collection datatype to cursor datatype `TYPE indx IS TABLE OF all_emp_cur%rowtype`.

Then your code should be like this:

```
DECLARE 

    Cursor emp_ID is SELECT Employee_ID FROM EMPLOYEES;
    Cursor all_emp_cur (ID employees.Employee_ID%TYPE) is 
              select a.first_name, A.EMAIL from employees a, job_history b
              where a.employee_id = b.EMPLOYEE_ID
              and b.employee_ID = ID;

    emp_rec employees%rowtype;
    TYPE indx IS TABLE OF all_emp_cur%rowtype
    INDEX BY pls_integer;
    indx_tab  indx;

    Tablecount number (10) := 0;
    Reccount  number (10) := 0;

BEGIN 

For ID_rec in emp_ID LOOP 
reccount := reccount + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

    Open all_emp_cur (ID_rec.Employee_ID) ;

    Fetch all_emp_cur bulk collect into indx_tab;
          Close all_emp_cur;

           /*FOR indx IN 1 .. indx_tab.count loop
           --dbms_output.put_line('Count: ' || rowcount)
           dbms_output.put_line('FIST NAME: ' || indx_tab(indx).fname);
           dbms_output.put_line('SALARY ' || indx_tab(indx).salary);

           --Begin: IF or Case Statements ---

          ---End: End If or Case Statements ---

          dbms_output.put_line('Row Count ' || Tablecount);*/

End Loop;

END;
```

You also can change the cursor to get all employees columns instead first_name and email. For example:

```
Cursor all_emp_cur (ID employees.Employee_ID%TYPE) is 
              select a.* from employees a, job_history b
              where a.employee_id = b.EMPLOYEE_ID
              and b.employee_ID = ID;

    emp_rec employees%rowtype;
    TYPE indx IS TABLE OF emp_rec%rowtype
    INDEX BY pls_integer;
    indx_tab  indx;
```

Comment: So you removed the exit when and End Loop of the 2nd cursor -- thank you for the help.                                                         As with the table and displaying the contents each time bulk collect is run, what you mean when you said "type of indx must be the same of the cursor"? Should the "indx" be changed to the name of the table or to 'i'? Please do clarify.

Comment: Aww...I figured out what you meant. That makes a lot of sense now.